# In Excel (2013) how do I get the value of grouped fields in subtotals

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

Using subtotals, I get the following:

[image]
*click to enlarge*

This is great, but when I collapse, I don't see what client (column A), project (column B), etc it is for. Is there a way to see the grouped (or last) column when collapsed.

Please without vba.

Comment: If I understand, you want to group rows(337:340) to collapse with the total from 340 showing, but with the information from (A339:D339)? So the bottom line for the group reads A339:D339, E340, J340? Or A339:D339,E340,F339:H339,J340? *and* you don't just want row 340 to show the information from 339?

Comment: Row 340 ABCD showing the same values as row 339 ABCD would be enough. Since 'Subtotals' are created on change of column E, ABCD are always the same per group.

Comment: Do you want row 340 ABCD only populated when the grouping is collapsed? Are you doing subtotals with `=subtotal` or some other way? Is it that you do the subtotal *after* the grouping is done?

Comment: I want to see row 340 ABCD when it's collapsed, so I can copy paste the totals to another sheet and do time calculations with it. I'm using the subtotal functionality from the ribbon.

Comment: You should try using a summary row [information](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Insert-subtotals-in-a-list-of-data-in-a-worksheet-7881d256-b4fa-4f81-b71e-b0a3d4a52b3a)